# С# Получить boolean из другого (произвольного) метода и поменять его

Tags: c#

Ситуация - есть неопределённое множество методов , и у них есть boolean показывающая активность например bool Active , спустя некоторое время (разное для разных методов) надо эту булеан поменять.

На текущий момент эту проблему я решаю заплаткой вида

```
private IEnumerator SwitchFlipper ( float duration )
{
    var durationTimerS = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (durationTimerS.Elapsed.TotalSeconds <= duration)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    Active = !Active;
    durationTimerS.Stop();
    durationTimerS.Reset();
}
```

Но мне хотелось бы иметь некий один метод который будет получать извне (от других методов) длительность и собственно какую переменную ему менять через это время.

Вопрос- это вообще возможно? (мне кажется да, я просто в C# не силён)
Если да то как это может быть реализовано?

Answer (score 1):

Да запросто. Например, так.

```
static async void ExecuteAfter(TimeSpan s, Action a)
{
    await Task.Delay(s);
    a();
}
```

и в том месте, где нужно поменять переменную:

```
bool v = true;
ExecuteAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => v = !v);
```

---

Учтите, что если вы не находитесь в UI-потоке, то вам неплохо бы синхронизировать обращение к переменной:

```
object m = new object();
ExecuteAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => { lock (m) v = !v; });
```

Если же вы выполняете в текущем потоке действия до наступления нужного момента времени, то проще, вероятно, всё же использовать сравнение времени:

```
var endTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
while (DateTime.Now < endTime)
{
    // выполнять какую-то работу
}
```

Comment: Спасибо общую идею я ухватил

Comment: Но вот что именно вы в этой строке ExecuteAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => { lock (m) v = !v; }); делаете я искренне не понял что делает lock?

Comment: @astion: Он делает синхронизацию на случай многопоточного доступа. Если доступ к переменной происходит из нескольких потоков, нужен lock.